# currently I'm saving json data in a string type of column, are there benefits to making the type json?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my project I am currently saving some json data in this column:

```
$table->string('meta')->nullable();
```

Are there any real benefits of using

```
$table->json('meta')->nullable();
```

Since my application must work with both MySQL and MariaDB I am not using any extra functions laravel offers for searching and updating json columns. So if we count these benefits out, are there any other benefits of using json over string for column that will be saving json data?

Comment: Field size would be a consideration. If saving a lot of json.

Comment: so json type offers much larger storage then string type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantages **JSON** over **String** are described in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

> Automatic validation of JSON documents stored in JSON columns. Invalid documents produce an error.
>
> Optimized storage format. JSON documents stored in JSON columns are converted to an internal format that permits quick read access to document elements. When the server later must read a JSON value stored in this binary format, the value need not be parsed from a text representation. The binary format is structured to enable the server to look up subobjects or nested values directly by key or array index without reading all values before or after them in the document.

And can add, that you can [create secondary index for json columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html).